# Cant reach end-points when running docker image

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm following a guide on how to dockerize a maven springboot server and I can run the docker image succesfully using "winpty docker run -it -p 9999:8080 springio/spring-docker-template" but I can't access any of its endpoints. Even though the output is indicating that Spring Boot is running.

Ive tried both localhost:8080/users/all and localhost:9999/users/all

If i run the application normally using "./mvnw package && java -jar target/spring-docker-template-0.1.0.jar" the end-points work fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","main.Application"]
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-docker-template</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>main.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- docker image prefix -->
        <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--docker -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- In this creates creates: springio/spring-docker-template -->
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Ensures that the jar is unpacked before the docker image -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The steps I've taken can be found in the readme here: https://github.com/tago-SE/Server-Dev-Labs/tree/master/spring-docker-template

Comment: You mentioned winpty so it looks like you are running on windows. If you are running docker toolbox on windows then you need to use 192.168.99.100 ip address instead of localhost

Comment: You are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the EXPOSE command to your dockerfile, might be that it is not exposing port 8080 and as such you can't access it.

Changed Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","main.Application"]
```

Build your image again, and try the following steps again.

Comment: Tried it and then executed "./mvnw install dockerfile:build" and "docker run -it -p 8080 :8080 springio/spring-docker-template". The problem remains.